# Make applications accessible to specific users?

Tags: macos, applications, user-account

I have an "Artist" user and a "Developer" user.

I'm wondering if there is a way to make system wide applications only accessible to certain users.
For example, I would like Pixelmator to only be accessible by the "Artist" user and for XCode to only be accessible by the "Developer" user.

Is this possible? Should I just `chmod o-rwx TheApplication.app` and place the users and apps in specific groups?

Comment: Are you really worried about them accessing those applications, or is it more about reducing clutter?

Comment: I dont want an Artist messing with XCode projects or things like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm wondering whether you could just move/install the required applications to a `~/Applications` directory (e.g. `/Users/Artist/Applications`), rather than `/Applications`. That way, particular applications in the local applications directory would only be available to that logged in user.

Alternatively, you could always enable [Parental Controls](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH4603) on the "Artist" account, then restrict the set of apps that user could run. The caveat being, that user account could no longer be an administrator.

[image]